# Game Maker Get Point On Path

Tags: path-finding, a-star, game-maker

I'm combining A* pathfinding with a steering AI so I can make the movement look more smooth and natural.  To do this, I'm calculating the path from the enemy to the player and using checkpoints on the path to have the steering AI move to.  However, from what I have seen the only way to get the x and y values of a certain point on a path, you need to use `path_get_point_x(path, n)` to get the x coord for the nth point of the path.  But, from what I've seen, the amount of points in a path are far too low for me to accurately move the enemy around obstacles.  Sometimes, the enemy goes through obstacles to get to the next point even though the path traces around the obstacle.  I noticed there is a variable called `path_position` that is a number from 0-1 representing how far into the path you are (1 being finished).  Is there a way to use that to predict where the player will be at position 0.3 of they're at position 0.25, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time objects will take the quickest path, or path of least resistance. Check precise collision detection for tiles that are bordering the pathways and see if that helps keep objects out of collision objects. As for a prediction to where they will be you can multiple the speed of the object by the frames per second.